# How to change the user used to push to a github repo on the command line?

Tags: git, github

In the local git setup there seems to be an incorrect username stored. When I run the command

```
git push --set-upstream origin feasture_branch
```

I get an error

```
ERROR: Permission to BlueBrain/Livre.git denied to alex4200.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I see immediately the user `alex4200` is incorrect.

How to change that "push" user for git in general on the command line (i.e. not just for the one repo, but in general for git...)?

I do not see that user defined in `~./gitconfig`, and a file `~/.git-credentials` does not exist.

Comment: What does `git config --list` output?

Comment: Output too long to post here. What are you looking for?

Comment: The user information that git is using.

Comment: user.email=some@email
user.password=835f4cb1e6159108b2c5aefd798347
user.name=adietz

Comment: The wrong user name is nowhere to be seen

Comment: Is the remote URL using SSH?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244188/discussion-between-alex-and-evolutionxbox).

Comment: yes. also does not matter. same error for ssh and https